# RadGridView Template Resource

Tags: silverlight

How to make template of this to be put in resource:

```
<telerikGridView:RadGridView x:Name="MyGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerikGridView:GridViewColumn Header="Id">
            <telerikGridView:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikGridView:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerikGridView:GridViewColumn>
        <telerikGridView:GridViewColumn Header="Name">
            <telerikGridView:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NAME}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikGridView:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerikGridView:GridViewColumn>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerikGridView:RadGridView>
```

I have 2 other grids that have same tamplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Dictionary file and add its reference in App.xaml

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resourses/DataTemplates.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Resource file content...

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" 
        mc:Ignorable="d">
            <DataTemplate x:Key="GridIDTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GridNameTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

And in your file reference Data Templates by name

```
<telerikGridView:RadGridView x:Name="MyGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerikGridView:GridViewColumn Header="Id" CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridIDTemplate}" />
             <telerikGridView:GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridNameTemplate}">
           </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerikGridView:RadGridView>
```